# Rails, ChartKick & MongoID queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

I have a Rails app that I want to use ChartKick to display some charts on the "Dashbaord" page. I have ChartKick installed and I am aware that I need to use MongoDB queries to pull the data but the data I am trying to pull and "count" is in a nested key, which on my main index views I got round by creating a new model and using `embeds_one` and `embedded_in` to pull the nested info into the main model.

I am now stuck on trying to get this nested info into a pie chart.

My models are as follows:-

```
class Vulnerability
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :id, type: String
  field :type, type: String
  field :description, type: String
  field :published, type: String
  field :modified, type: String
  field :href, type: String
  embeds_one :cvss
end
```

Secondary model:

```
class Cvss
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :score, type: Integer
  field :vector, type: String
  embedded_in :vulnerability
end
```

Which means I can use `<td><%= vulnerability.cvss.score %></td>` in my index view to pull through the values of 'Score'

My Dashboard view is blank except some rendered shared layouts and the following code for the pie chart:
`<%= pie_chart Vulnerability.collection.aggregate("$group" => { "score" => "$name", count: {"$sum" => 1}}) %>`

This gives the error `no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer`

The Mongo documents are stored as follows:

```
{
    "_id" : "CESA-2017:3081",
    "_index" : "bulletins",
    "_score" : null,
    "sort" : [
        103042
    ],
    "lastseen" : "2017-10-30T20:42:09",
    "references" : [
        "https://access.redhat.com/errata/RHSA-2017:3081"
    ],
    "affectedPackage" : [
        {
            "OS" : "CentOS",
            "OSVersion" : "7",
            "packageVersion" : "7.0.76-3.el7_4",
            "arch" : "noarch",
            "packageFilename" : "",
            "packageName" : "",
            "operator" : "lt"
        },
    ],
    "description" : "",
    "edition" : 1,
    "reporter" : "CentOS Project",
    "published" : "2017-10-30T11:36:20",
    "title" : "tomcat security update",
    "type" : "centos",
    "enchantments" : {

    },
    "bulletinFamily" : "unix",
    "cvelist" : [

    ],
    "modified" : "",
    "id" : "",
    "href" : "",
    "cvss" : {
        "score" : 6.8,
        "vector" : "AV:NETWORK/AC:MEDIUM/Au:NONE/C:PARTIAL/I:PARTIAL/A:PARTIAL/"
    }
}
```

I have redacted some info from the Mongo document for readability as I do not use these keys/info but they get inserted from another application.

My development log shows the following:

```
Started GET "/admin" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-11-23 13:13:01 +0000
Processing by Admin::ApplicationController#index as HTML
  User Load (31.3ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
  Rendering admin/application/index.html.erb within admin/layouts/admin
  Rendered admin/application/index.html.erb within admin/layouts/admin (5.2ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 161ms (ActiveRecord: 31.3ms)



TypeError - no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer:
  app/views/admin/application/index.html.erb:4:in `_app_views_admin_application_index_html_erb__448509050785199124_47309549846040'

Started POST "/__better_errors/760bcb2acc441dc3/variables" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-11-23 13:13:01 +0000
```

Comment: Please share the view file which is breaking.

Comment: The view is just `<h3>Dashboard Stuff</h3>


<%= pie_chart Vulnerability.collection.aggregate("$group" => { "score" => "$name", count: {"$sum" => 1}}) %>`

Comment: So, the error occurs while rendering this view?

Comment: Please share the stacktrace also

Comment: Yes, when I load the view I get the error. I'll update the main question with the stack trace

Comment: "Yes, when I load the view I get the error." - Then, your "Dashboard Stuff" might have something wrong with it. Lets see the stack trace.  :)

Comment: I'm using Better Errors so this doesn't give a nice stack trace as its rendering the errors in a readable format and the development log just shows `Started GET "/admin" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-11-23 13:13:01 +0000
  Rendering admin/application/index.html.erb within admin/layouts/admin
  Rendered admin/application/index.html.erb within admin/layouts/admin (5.2ms)

TypeError - no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer:
  app/views/admin/application/index.html.erb:4:in `_app_views_admin_application_index_html_erb__448509050785199124_47309549846040'
`

Comment: Please paste the stack trace into question itself so that others can also help. And make it longer 15-20 lines at least. Also paste the line no: 4 from index.html.erb.

Comment: Where is the stack trace?? line 4 is blank

Comment: I mean the development log you pasted in comment above. 15-20 lines of it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159684/discussion-between-jagdeep-singh-and-luke).